# Codeigniter session SET on one server but not on another

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm stuck with a login function in Codeigniter which works on localhost and on my test server but session seems to be NOT SET on the 3rd server.

here's the do_login function of the 'home' controller :

```
public function do_login() {
        if ($this->session->userdata('is_admin_login')) {
            redirect('admin/home/dashboard');
        } else {
            $user = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
                $this->load->view('admin/vwLogin');
            } else {
                $salt = '5&JDDGKGlwz%sRghewh!t2Yg-Igae@QxgakPzFTSId';
                $enc_pass  = md5($salt.$password);
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_admin_users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";
                $val = $this->db->query($sql,array($user ,$enc_pass ));

                if ($val->num_rows) {
                    foreach ($val->result_array() as $recs => $res) {
                        $sess_array = array(
                            'id' => $res['id'],
                            'username' => $res['username'],
                            'email' => $res['email'],                            
                            'is_admin_login' => true,
                            'user_type' => $res['user_type']
                            );
                        $this->session->set_userdata($sess_array);
                    }
                    redirect('admin/dashboard');
                } else {
                    $err['error'] = '<strong>Access Denied</strong> Invalid Username/Password';
                    $this->load->view('admin/vwLogin', $err);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

On all 3 places (localhost, test server and production server) this function redirects to 'admin/dashboard' and there comes the difference.
Here's the dashboard controller :

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        dump_exit($this->session->userdata);
        if (!$this->session->userdata('is_admin_login')) {
            redirect('admin/home');
        }
    }

    public function index() {
        $arr['page']='dash';
        $this->load->view('admin/vwDashboard',$arr);
    }

}
```

When I dump_exit the session data in the constructor, 'is_admin_login' is TRUE @ localhost and the test server BUT it is not set on the production server. SAME CODE. I have tried to modify $config['cookie_domain'], $config['sess_expiration'], I have tried to REFRESH redirect('URL', 'refresh') all without success... 
In autoload.php I have :

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'form_validation');
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form', 'dump');
```

Any help or suggestion would be highly appreciated!

Comment: In your `application/config.php` file, what are the values in `$config['cookie_domain']` and `$config['cookie_path']` ??

Comment: I have tried all thee 3 :
$config['cookie_domain'] = "";
$config['cookie_path'] = "/";

$config['cookie_domain'] = "mydomain.com";
$config['cookie_path'] = "/";

$config['cookie_domain'] = ".mydomain.com";
$config['cookie_path'] = "/";

Comment: Please contact any server admin. as this is problem in server

Comment: Could be a WordPress configuration issue? On the production server I have WP installed. My CI project is in a separate folder on the web root.

Comment: make sure ur query returns a row  print the result_array()

Comment: thanks @pradeep as I said in the question, the script works on localhost and on the test server.